# Failed to access keys as result of aws_kms_info ansible module

Tags: arraylist, ansible

I have simple ansible playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local

  vars:
    frame_platform_region: us-east-1
    frame_site_name: sysmiromis
    frame_generated_vars_path: "/opt/frame/ssl/generated_vars.yml"

  tasks:
    - name: Get Vault KMS info
      aws_kms_info:
        region: "{{ frame_platform_region }}"
        filters:
          tag-key: Name
          tag-value: "Frame_Vault_KMS_key_{{ frame_site_name }}"
      register: vault_aws_kms

    - debug:
        msg: "{{ vault_aws_kms }}"
```

And result is  following:

```
TASK [debug] *********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": {
        "changed": false,
        "failed": false,
        "keys": [
            {
                "aliases": [
                    "Frame_Vault_KMS_key_sysmiromis20201104191816864800000001"
                ],
                "aws_account_id": "275695177179",
                "creation_date": "2020-10-20T16:27:39.586000+00:00",
                "customer_master_key_spec": "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT",
                "description": "Frame KMS key for Vault",
                "enabled": true,
                "encryption_algorithms": [
                    "SYMMETRIC_DEFAULT"
                ],
                "grants": [],
                "key_arn": "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:275695177179:key/11bec1ad-eb00-4a4d-a7a1-d4ac84a22d43",
                "key_id": "11bec1ad-eb00-4a4d-a7a1-d4ac84a22d43",
                "key_manager": "CUSTOMER",
                "key_state": "Enabled",
                "key_usage": "ENCRYPT_DECRYPT",
                "origin": "AWS_KMS",
                "policies": [
                    "{\n  \"Version\" : \"2012-10-17\",\n  \"Id\" : \"key-default-1\",\n  \"Statement\" : [ {\n    \"Sid\" : \"Enable IAM Role Permissions\",\n    \"Effect\" : \"Allow\",\n    \"Principal\" : {\n      \"AWS\" : [ \"arn:aws:iam::275695177179:root\", \"arn:aws:iam::275695177179:role/FrameVault\" ]\n    },\n    \"Action\" : \"kms:*\",\n    \"Resource\" : \"*\"\n  } ]\n}"
                ],
                "tags": {
                    "Name": "Frame_Vault_KMS_key_sysmiromis"
                }
            }
        ]
```

I need to access key_id  from above list. I have tried in many different ways -

```
"{{ vault_aws_kms.keys.key_id }}"
"{{ vault_aws_kms.keys[0] }}"
```

but it would always give an error like:

{"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'builtin_function_or_method object' has no attribute 'key_id'\n\n

Any idea how I  can  access any element from keys list above?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any idea how I can access any element from keys list above?

It's because `keys` is [a method on `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/stdtypes.html#dict.keys) and almost every "object" in ansible/jinja2 is a `dict`. You can side-step that method resolution via the `["keys"]` syntax:

```yaml
    - debug:
        msg: key_id is {{ vault_aws_kms["keys"][0].key_id }}
```

---

the followup question in the comments about the quotes would be

method A:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_key_id: '{{ vault_aws_kms["keys"][0].key_id }}'
```

method B:

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_key_id: "{{ vault_aws_kms['keys'][0].key_id }}"
```

method C

```yaml
- set_fact:
    my_key_id: >-
      {{ vault_aws_kms["keys"][0].key_id }}
```

Comment: Thank you mdaniel, this works. My use case is further to assign this value to variable, like 

- set_fact:
        frame_vault_aws_kms_key_id: "{{ vault_aws_kms["keys"][0].key_id }}"
but this does not work because of double quotation mark. I managed to achieve this somehow by debug msg, like you stated , and then  using regex filter  output more... Do you know more elegant solution to assign output of aws_kms_info to variable directly?

Comment: Yes, you can change the outer quotes to be `'`, or you can change the inner string literal quote to `'`, or you can use yaml scalar folding to get out of the outer quoting game entirely; I'll update the answer to show it

Comment: Great, then please accept the answer to let others know it worked for you